# oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout working but weirdly behaving

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm trying to configure read timeout for a query using dbcp. If query execution takes more than one minute, I want to time out the query.  My datasource is.If i put 250 then it is timing out after 27 seconds.i think 250 is in milliseconds but it is timing out wrongly.can you please help me how to set the value for oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout.

```
<bean id="appDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
  <property name="username" value="${app.jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" val="${app.jdbc.password}" />
  <prop name="connectionproperties" val="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=2000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: If the property is called `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout`, then why are you trying to set a property called `jdbc.ReadTimeout`? Names are important. BTW: You might need to set value `"oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=2000;"`

Comment: keep in mind readtime also means the db is working and hasn't responded yet.

Comment: Mark i have put "oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=2000;" but no luck.It is not timing out..

Comment: Kris rice,please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the JDBC driver version that you are using?